# Can't take my data out of the functions (Javascript & jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, get

I want to take `arrayDevice`, `arrayidDevice`, `arrayDomCommande`, `arrayidCommande` from outside of my function `lectureCommand`,  but I don't know how to take all these values and put them outside of this function to use it after.

This is my code:

```
function getCommand () {
        var nameDevice = []; 
        var idDevice = []; 
        var nomCommande= []; 
        var idCommande= []; 
        $.ajax({
            url:'/core-command/api/v1/device',
            type: 'GET',
            success:function(device){

                    for (var i in device)
                    {
                        // Noms des périphériques 
                        //console.log(device[i].name);
                        nameDevice = device[i].name;

                        // Noms des id du device
                        //console.log(device[i].id);
                        idDevice = device[i].id;

                        // Nom des commandes du device 
                        // console.log(device[i].commands[i]);
                        nomCommande = device[i].commands[0].name;

                        // id de la commande 
                        //console.log(device[i].commands[0].id);
                        idCommande = device[i].commands[0].id;
                        lectureCommand(nameDevice,idDevice,nomCommande,idCommande); 

                    }
             }

        });
    }
    // Declaration 
    arrayDevice = [];
    arrayidDevice = []; 
    arrayDomCommande = []; 
    arrayidCommande = []; 
    arrayDescription = [];

    function lectureCommand(nameDevice,idDevice,nomCommande,idCommande) 
    {
        arrayDevice.push(nameDevice);
        arrayidDevice.push(idDevice);
        arrayDomCommande.push(nomCommande);
        arrayidCommande.push(idCommande);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is small mistake is in your code.

Suppose Ajax success function is like this:

```
function ajaxsuccess(){
    lectureCommand(1,2,3,4);//testing with 1,2,3,4 args...
}
```

When you call `getCommand()` function then your code is executed as:

```js
function ajaxsuccess(){
    lectureCommand(1,2,3,4);
}
ajaxsuccess();

    arrayDevice = [];
    arrayidDevice = []; 
    arrayDomCommande = []; 
    arrayidCommande = []; 
    arrayDescription = [];

    function lectureCommand(nameDevice,idDevice,nomCommande,idCommande) 
    {
        arrayDevice.push(nameDevice);
        arrayidDevice.push(idDevice);
        arrayDomCommande.push(nomCommande);
        arrayidCommande.push(idCommande);
    }
console.log(arrayDevice,arrayidDevice,arrayDomCommande,arrayidCommande);
```

See the error in snippet:

> "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: arrayDevice is not defined"

That means `arrayDevice` is undefined variable for `lectureCommand()` function also. Hence you are pushing value in undefined array(`arrayDevice.push(nameDevice)`)

Solution of this problem is to define global variables at the start of the script, see the working snippet:

```js
//Define global variables at start of the script...
    arrayDevice = [];
    arrayidDevice = []; 
    arrayDomCommande = []; 
    arrayidCommande = []; 
    arrayDescription = [];

function ajaxsuccess(){
    lectureCommand(1,2,3,4);
}
ajaxsuccess();    
    function lectureCommand(nameDevice,idDevice,nomCommande,idCommande) 
    {
        arrayDevice.push(nameDevice);
        arrayidDevice.push(idDevice);
        arrayDomCommande.push(nomCommande);
        arrayidCommande.push(idCommande);
    }
console.log(arrayDevice,arrayidDevice,arrayDomCommande,arrayidCommande);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, but i still have a problem when i try after the function lectureCommand to access to my arrays, it doesn't work, 
I did some console.log() to try and i have :

// This is what i get with console.log("test "+ arrayDevice[0])
 : test undefined

// This is what i get inside ajax for device[i].name
: VM641:25 ajax Random-Integer-Generator01
: VM641:25 ajax Random-Boolean-Device
=> VM641:25 ajax Random-Integer-Device
VM641:25 ajax Random-UnsignedInteger-Device
VM641:25 ajax Random-Float-Device

// This is what i get with console.log(arrayDevice) 
:
[]
0: "Random-Integer-Generator01"
1: "Random-Boolean-Device"
2: "Random-Integer-Device"
3: "Random-UnsignedInteger-Device"
4: "Random-Float-Device"

This is my modified code :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
          // Declaration 
        arrayDevice = [];
        arrayidDevice = []; 
        arrayDomCommande = []; 
        arrayidCommande = []; 
        arrayDescription = [];

        // Get des données lues dans core-data
        function getCommand () {
            var nameDevice = []; 
            var idDevice = []; 
            var nomCommande= []; 
            var idCommande= []; 
            $.ajax({
                url:'/core-command/api/v1/device',
                type: 'GET',
                success:function(device){

                        for (var i in device)
                        {
                            // Noms des périphériques 
                            console.log("ajax "+ device[i].name);
                            nameDevice = device[i].name;

                            // Noms des id du device
                            //console.log(device[i].id);
                            idDevice = device[i].id;

                            // Nom des commandes du device 
                            // console.log(device[i].commands[i]);
                            nomCommande = device[i].commands[0].name;

                            // id de la commande 
                            //console.log(device[i].commands[0].id);
                            idCommande = device[i].commands[0].id;
                            lectureCommand(nameDevice,idDevice,nomCommande,idCommande); 

                        }

                 }

            });
        }

        function lectureCommand(nameDevice,idDevice,nomCommande,idCommande) 
        {
            arrayDevice.push(nameDevice);
            arrayidDevice.push(idDevice);
            arrayDomCommande.push(nomCommande);
            arrayidCommande.push(idCommande);
        }
      console.log("test "+ arrayDevice[0]);
```